# Records of empty data being returned from Xamarin.iOS SQLite db for one or more tables

Tags: ios, sqlite, xamarin.ios

I've been facing this problem for the past few days. I am attempting to create a table view that is populated from a database query (seems simple enough). As I will be managing multiple tables, I have created a database helper class to fetch the data by using the sql queries. But it does not work consistently (or at all of late).

When I attempt to query a table, using one of the defined functions, the db return cursors with XX number of records, but null column data. In effect, multiple rows ( I see the row separators), but each row is blank.

Any suggestion or help is highly appreciated.

Comment: We can't help you if you don't show us what you're doing.  Please post the relevant portions of your code.

Comment: public IEnumerable<AMSClass> GetAllAMSClass()
  {
   return  Query<AMSClass>("select * from AMSClass ORDER BY name ASC");                      
  }                                                                                                                        This method is returning the list of the AMS classes present in the database, it's returning XX number of items but when i am going to access any property of the AMSClass then it returns null for all the Items. It happens when I convert the App from 32bit to 64 bit.